# Two timed jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the page there are multiple buttons, if the user is inactive a timeout prompt appears in the div black-bg. That part works fine. I'm trying to redirect the page if the user doesn't click the "Click to Continue" button after 10 seconds we redirect to index.html. That's where I'm stuck.

Any help would be very useful. I apreciate it.

```
var SessionTime=10000;
var tickDuration=1000;
var myInterval=setInterval(function(){
    SessionTime=SessionTime-tickDuration
},1000);
var myTimeOut=setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);

$(".extend").click(function(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    SessionTime=10000;
    myTimeOut=setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);
});

function SessionExpireEvent(){ 
    $("div#black-bg").addClass('fade-in' );

    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "index.html"; 
     }, 20000); 

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
        SessionTime=10000;
        myTimeOut=setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);
        $("div#black-bg").removeClass('fade-in' );
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="extend" href="5.html">
    <div class="man-container">
    </div>
</a>

<a class="extend" href="4.html">
    <div class="inflamation-container">             
        <div class="lables">
        </div>                            
    </div>
</a>

<div id="container-inner">
    <div id="black-bg">
        <div class="alert-container">
            <h2 class="white-txt">Your Session Has Expired</h2>
            <button class="reset">Click to continue</button>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also post the related HTML code?

Comment: The inner timeout inside the `SessionExpireEvent` is not being set to a variable that can be cleared, if they click an element with the class of reset.  So it's never going to be cancelled and will always redirect the user after 20 seconds.

Comment: There's also no point in clearing the `myTimeOut` inside `SessionExpireEvent`.  The only way the logic will get into that method is if the timeout already transpired.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why you need an interval that decrements **SessionTime**. Second, entry point should be `$(document).ready()` I will do like this:

```
var SessionTime = 10000;
var myTimeOut;
var redirectTimeout;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Start timeout for session expiration.

    myTimeOut = setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);

    // Register click event listener on elements with ".extend" class.

    $(".extend").click(function()
    {
        // Restart timeout for session expiration.
        clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
        myTimeOut = setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);
    });
});

function SessionExpireEvent()
{
    $("div#black-bg").addClass('fade-in');

    redirectTimeout = setTimeout(function()
    {
        window.location.href = "index.html"; 
    }, 20000);

    $(".reset").unbind("click").click(function()
    {
        // Stop redirection timeout.
        clearTimeout(redirectTimeout);

        // Restart session expiration timeout
        clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
        myTimeOut = setTimeout(SessionExpireEvent,SessionTime);
        $("div#black-bg").removeClass('fade-in');
    });
}
```